# Example that the union of sigma algebra is not an algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I've tried to find the one, but failed to solve it. 
Some people asked similar question, but all the answers were about the case that "the union of sigma-algebra is not a 'sigma-algebra'". 
What I want to know is this ; what is the example that the union of sigma algebra is not "an algebra"? And how can I prove it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean two sets that have a sigma algebra on them that the union of them is not an algebra, that's pretty trivial.    Take the power sets of two completely different sets.   Say $P(\mathbb R)$  and $P(\text {set of all finite words generated from two letters \{a,b\}})$.    Each is a sigma algebra under the usual set operations.  Take the union of those two sets, and you don't even have an algebra, as $\{0\}\cup \{ab\}$ is not in the union of those two power sets

Comment: Or, just you know, $\{a,\varnothing\}$ and $\{b,\varnothing\}$ when $a\neq b$.

Comment: What if the two sets are on the same set space? I mean the power set X {F1, F2...} is a collection of sigma-algebra on Ω, which is finite.